# Error while installing spellchecker for LibreOffice

Tags: 10.10, libreoffice, spell-checking

When I run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install aspell aspell-en dictionaries-common hunspell-en-us myspell-en-us
```

I get the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hunspell-en-us : Conflicts: myspell-en-us but 1:3.2.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

I used [this guide to install LibreOffice](http://drupal.txwikinger.me.uk/content/libreoffice-now-available-ppa-ubuntu-1010-and-1004).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hunspell-en-us : Conflicts: myspell-en-us but 1:3.2.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed

This simply means that you cannot install both at the same time.